# Verify page title in Selenium Webdriver using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, page-title

I am new with ruby but familiar with selenium and I want to verify the title of the page (for example we use `assertEquals` with java). I tried finding everywhere but couldn't find anything suitable for ruby.

```
verify_title = driver.title
assertEquals("Page Title" , driver.getTitle()); //want to change this line in ruby
```

P.S. I want to use it without the help of cucumber.

Comment: `verify_title = driver.getTitle()` - have you tried this?

Comment: @Brian My question is how to verify the title of the page? (not getting the title)

Comment: My apologies, I misread.  `string pageTitle = driver.getTitle(); string expectedTitle = "Your page title here"; assertEquals(pageTitle, expectedTitle);`

Comment: @Brian I don't think so it'll work in Ruby. (It'll work in java but not Ruby)

Comment: In Ruby, it is `verifyTitle` if memory serves.  I merely send that code example as a clean way to do what you are wanting.  The [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/).

Answer (score 2):

```
assertEquals( "Page Title", driver.title )
```

I don't know which test framework you are using, but you'll need to change `assertEquals`.

See the Ruby example [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example).

Comment: I tried looking into the documentations of ruby but couldn't able to find anything for the assertEquals.

Comment: If you want to use Test::Unit, `assert_equal`. See assertions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#available-assertions

Comment: It worked! Thanks. Had to add `include Test::Unit::Assertions` and then added `assert_equal(expectedPageTitle, "ActualPageTitle", "Page Title not correct" )`

Comment: @BSeven You're missing a closing "

Comment: @HaemEternal - Thanks